# Change single click editing to double click in grid

Tags: kendo-ui

I want to replace the single click editing functionality on kendo ui grid into double click.

The settings i want to keep are: `selectable: "multiple, row", editable: true`

I found that a solution is to set the `editable: false` and add a `$('#grid').delegate('tbody>tr>td','dblclick', function (e){}`

Unfortunately this brings up other problems making my entire editing process difficult. For example, kendo cannot track anymore the changes that easily, does not mark the field as being changed with that red arrow.

Is there a way to change the default kendo single click functionality into double click?

So the requested behaviour would be:

1. Single click selects row/cell
2. Double click brings cell into edit mode.

Comment: You can check another way to do this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20842058/how-to-handle-a-kendo-ui-grid-row-double-click-event

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not very *nice* but might do the trick:

```
var myGrid = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid");
myGrid.element.on('click', 'tbody>tr>td:not(.k-edit-cell)', function (e) {
    myGrid.closeCell();
});
myGrid.element.on("dblclick", "tbody>tr>td:not(.k-edit-cell)", "dblclick", function (e) {
    myGrid.editCell($(this));
});
```

The first `on` exits the edition of the cell for a single click and do not change other binding as row selection, the second enters in edition mode for the cell.

Why do I say *nice*? Because I would prefer to `unbind` the previous `click` event for edition (only) than having to close the edition.

Comment: At one point your suggestion works. Yes when double clicking on a cell it does truly enable it and puts it in edit mode. Unfortunately once you try to press again in the edit field, for example to select/mark the text, or just press in the edited field, the cell again closes .

Comment: @Stephan, I have modified the code adding extra condition in the selector (basically do nothing if the cell is in edition mode).

Comment: Just noticed that the above code generates the following error when trying to edit a numeric field. NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMHTMLInputElement.setSelectionRange] [Break On This Error]  
element.setSelectionRange(position, position); on line kendo.web.js (line 29562). From what i found here http://en.usenet.digipedia.org/thread/14444/19066/ it seems that it is more Firefox related, as i cannot reproduce it in Chrome, IE 8. But i still do not know if i should see that error

Comment: Furthermore it seems that the above code generates problem when i have a validation in a field. For example, i have a numeric field and enter a number different than in my validation pattern. The error message (inside the tooltip) appears only when i press right on the row below the edited field. When i press 2-3 lines below, then the message appears and disappears instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code, it's ugly but works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("dblclick", "#MyGrid td[role='gridcell']", function (e) {   
        // do something
        });
    });
</script>
```