# How to handle a Kendo UI Grid row double-click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a selectable KendoUI grid in my MVC app. I want to do something when the user double-clicks on the grid.

I don't see a double-click event for the grid.

How may I handle the double-click event when there is none exposed?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the standard double click event. The first click will select the grid row, adding a `.k-state-selected` class to it, and the second click will trigger the double click event.

```
$("#yourgridname").on("dblclick", "tr.k-state-selected", function () {
    // insert code here
});
```

Comment: I am sure that's the way as I googled it a lot, but it doesn't work for me. I don't know what it is I am doing that is wrong.

Comment: That's weird, I use that exact same method on a particular project and it works for me. What do you want to do when the user double-clicks the grid?

Comment: I want to get the data of the row he double-clicked on. It is a selectable grid. I have now removed the double-click event handler and put a Select button there. Please help me by answering this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858763/get-selected-row-data-in-kendo-ui-grid

Answer (score 10):

You can also use `dataBound`

```
dataBound: function (e) {
   var grid = this;
   grid.tbody.find("tr").dblclick(function (e) {
      var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);
      ...
    });
}
```

from http://www.telerik.com/forums/double-click-on-grid-row-with-angular

Comment: This is by far the simplest and cleanest solution I found on the web. Maybe add that dataBound is a Kendo UI grid config.

Comment: To get this to work I needed to change the second line to `const grid = e.sender;`.

Comment: This approach adds an event handler to every `tr` element. So if you have a thousand rows, you'll end up with a thousand event handlers. Better use a delegated event handler instead of a directly bound event handler.

Answer (score 3):

With [kendoHelpers](https://github.com/salarcode/kendoHelpers) you can get the dataItem of the row.
https://github.com/salarcode/kendoHelpers

```
kendoHelpers.grid.eventRowDoubleClick (theGrid, 
    function(dataItem){
        // do stuff with dataItem
    });
```

It also has `eventCellDoubleClick` which works on cells.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to handle it:

```
var grid = $('#myGrid').kendoGrid({
    columnMenu: true,
    filterable: true,
    selectable: true,
    // and many more configuration stuff...
}).data('kendoGrid');

grid.tbody.delegate('tr', 'dblclick', function() {
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this));
    // do whatever you like with the row data...
});
```

Since v3.0, `delegate` has been deprecated. You can use `on`, like so:

```
grid.tbody.on('dblclick', 'tr', function() {
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this));
    // do whatever you like with the row data...
});
```

Comment: This approach worked better for me - the `dblclick(function (e) {...});` event handler failed after a row was edited (inline).