# How can I access the model for the selected item in a Kendo UI Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a selectable kendoUI grid in my ASP.NET MVC app. How do I get the strongly typed model object for the selected item? I have tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Backup>(Model.Backups)
    .Name("MatchingBackupsGrid")
    .Columns(col =>
        {
            col.Bound(backup => backup.BackupUId).Title("UID");
            col.Bound(backup => backup.BackupFirstName).Title("First Name");
            col.Bound(backup => backup.BackupLastName).Title("Last Name");
        })
        .Scrollable()
        .Selectable(sel =>
        {
            sel.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single);
            sel.Type(GridSelectionType.Row);
        })
         .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Server()
            .Read(read => read.Action("SearchForBackup", "Arr", new { lastName = Model.SearchTerm }))
            .Model(model => model.Id(backup => backup.BackupUId))
         )
    )

function SelectBackupButtonClickHandler() {

    var grid = $("#MatchingBackupsGrid").data("kendoGrid");

    var selectedBackup = grid.dataItem(grid.select());

    console.log(selectedBackup);
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Did you check that `SelectBackupButtonClickHandler` is actually invoked? Did you check that `grid,select()` actually returns anything?

Comment: FYI the function is not wrapped in a <script> element.

Comment: Sorry, guys, I just posted the relevant snippet in one go. I have the JavaScript code in a proper script tag and the event listener is being called, and the `grid.select()` also does return a proper array with just 1 item in it. I just don't know how to get from there to a strongly typed model object.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have no idea what it was that I was doing earlier, my code is working now.

I tried so many things -- I assumed for some reason that `grid.select()` returns an array, so I tried to apply an indexer to get the first element of the array like so:

```
var selectedBackups = grid.select();

// strangely, the Visual Studio intellisense mislead 
// me here as it showed me the model properties on 
// indexing this array
selectedBackups[0].BackupFirstName;
```

I also tried a transformation on the array like so:

```
var names = $.map(grid.select(), function(item)
{
    return item.BackupFirstName + ' ' + item.BackupLastName;
});
```

I was in between so many ideas I was trying that I forgot to check that my original code *did* actually have a strongly typed model of the selected row.

So, just for the record, the code in the question is correct, and it is reproduced below. To get the selected item in a single selection mode KendoUI grid, do the following:

```
var grid = $("#MatchingBackupsGrid").data("kendoGrid");

// this is a single object and not an array
// this is your strongly typed model object
var selectedBackup = grid.dataItem(grid.select());

console.log(selectedBackup);
```

Comment: all you get from grid.select() is a JavaScript object - it will  have all properties, but it is _not_ the strongly typed model you interact with on the server-side; it's fine if your problem is solved, however if your question was really caused by a mistake or misunderstanding, then you should either close your question (since it was invalid) or accept the answer that was correct for what you were asking for

Answer (score 1):

Grid row selection responds to the Kendo `change` event.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Backup>(Model.Backups)
    .Name("MatchingBackupsGrid")
    .Columns(col =>
        {
            col.Bound(backup => backup.BackupUId).Title("UID");
            col.Bound(backup => backup.BackupFirstName).Title("First Name");
            col.Bound(backup => backup.BackupLastName).Title("Last Name");
        })
        .Scrollable()
        .Selectable(sel =>
        {
            sel.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single);
            sel.Type(GridSelectionType.Row);
        })
         .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Server()
            .Read(read => read.Action("SearchForBackup", "Arr", new { lastName = Model.SearchTerm }))
            .Model(model => model.Id(backup => backup.BackupUId))
         )
    )
<script>
function SelectBackupButtonClickHandler() {
    var selectedBackup = this.dataItem(this.select());
    console.log(selectedBackup);
}

$("#MatchingBackupsGrid").data("kendoGrid").bind("change", SelectBackupButtonClickHandler);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're using client-side code, you can only access client-side data; you can't access the strongly typed model using `grid.dataItem()`. If you want to do that, you'll need to send the item's id to the server, e.g. using an AJAX request, and continue your work there; so you'll have to do something like this:

```
function SelectBackupButtonClickHandler() {
    var grid = $("#MatchingBackupsGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var selectedBackup = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
    var id = selectedBackup.id;

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: yourUrl, // post to your controller action that does what you want to do with the model
       dataType: "json",
       data: { id: id } 
    };
}
```

Comment: According to the Kendo UI docs, the client-side `change` event (which works on selection) is supported for server binding mode: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/server-binding (scroll to bottom)

Comment: @EfrainReyes the way I read that, it says that these events will be _raised_ in server-binding mode, but it doesn't mean that you can execute server-side code in them (because they're still client-side events) - then again, I don't have extensive knowledge of the MVC wrappers, so maybe there's a better way to do this  (although I assume it'll have to work in a similar way, ultimately)

Comment: Sorry, @LarsHöppner. The client *does* get a complete model. I see it in my console/debugger/browser debugger tools. I don't know what it was that I was doing wrong. I was indexing the selectedBackup assuming it was an array. And then I was, at one time, mapping each item of the array to something.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 What do you mean by "complete" model? Of course it will have all the data, but it will be a JavaScript object, not the strongly typed model you interact with on the server, which is what you were asking for.

Answer (score 0):

With [kendoHelpers](https://github.com/salarcode/kendoHelpers) you can get the selected item's dataItem

```
// Get the grid
var grid = $('#SampleGrid').data('kendoGrid');

// Call your desired function
var dataItem = kendoHelpers.grid.getSelectedDataItem(grid);

// Manipulate the results
if (dataItem != null){
    // dataItem.MyId = ...
}
```

The other method which is `getSelectedDataItemByCurrentCell` doesn't require the grid to be selectable and works on the active cell.

The library also has many other helper functions.