# Kendo UI DoubleClick does not work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I tried to implement a DoubleClick Event like discribed in Article [How to handle a Kendo UI Grid row double-click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20842058/how-to-handle-a-kendo-ui-grid-row-double-click-event)

Unfortunatlely I do not get it working.

I Use the Following Code: ("grid" is a Div in which the Kendo Grid is generated)

```
function generateGrid(gridData) {
var parsedData = JSON.parse(gridData);

var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: parsedData,
    batch: true,
    pageSize: 20
});

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    height: 680,
    sortable: true,
    selectable: true,
    pageable: true,
    filterable: true,
    columnmenue: true,
    scrollable: false
});

var g = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
g.setDataSource(dataSource);

g.on("dblclick", "tr.k-state-selected", function () {
    alert("Double Click");
});
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing some minor mistakes like:

- bind dblClick event on kendoGrid return object, not on jquery selector object
- targeting dblClick event only on rows containing class 'k-state-selected'

  Try this:

  `$("#grid").on("dblclick", "tr", function() {
           alert('double click');
  });`

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/proghdtt/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using the JQuery Selector did the Trick